# Gauge issue - target value doesn't show up

Tags: visualization, powerbi

I'm trying to create some visuals for a report in Power Bi, and I have this issue with a Gauge Visualization. I introduce the Total Revenues and Total Revenues (target) measures as Value and Target value, respectively. I've checked, and the formulas for these measures are correct and seem to be working. However, the Gauge won't display any target value.
How can I fix this? Thank!